# JSON.parse add property or func?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Is there any way to use JSON.parse function to ADD properties or functions on newly created objects (whatever their nesting level is) ?

Using reviver option (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
 I understand I can drop properties I don't want or care when parsing a json.

```
JSON.parse(
'{"name":"toplevel",'+
' "gibberish":"...",'+
' "children":['+
'   {"name":"child1",'+
'    "gibberish":"..."'+
'   },'+
'   {"name":"child2",'+
'    "gibberish":"..."'+
'   }'+
' ]'+
'}'
 ,(key,value)=>{
 if (key=="gibberish")
 {
  return undefined;
 }
 return value
});

=>
{"name":"toplevel"
 "children":[
   {"name":"child1"},
   {"name":"child2"}
 ]
}
```

the code above remove the gibberish property of all objects created.
Now What could I do to ADD a property (say uniqueID) ?

Should i traverse the object tree again ? (and deal with typeOf (and its bug) to guess if a property is a object rather than null or Array or ...)

Comment: After you parse it, its a JS object.  You can add whatever you want to it then, including adding properties.

Comment: My problem is about nesting. I want to add funcs on all Objects no matter how deep they are.

Comment: what you mean _I want to add funcs on all Objects_? Can you add sample output?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that has the behavior you want and then assign the JSON data to an instance.

```
function Class() {...}
Class.prototype.accept = function(visitor) {...};
Class.prototype.copyFromJSON = function() {
    delete this.gibberish;
    this.children = this.children.map(function(child) {
        child = Object.assign(new ChildClass, child);
        child.copyFromJSON();
        return child;
    });
};
function ChildClass() {...}
ChildClass.prototype.copyFromJSON = function() {
    delete this.gibberish;
    ...
}
var instance = Object.assign(new Class, JSON.parse(json));
instance.copyFromJSON();
```

Comment: This will only work for the top level instance. I'm looking for something that handle nesting.

Comment: See updated example above. You need to implement the nested behavior for assigning types to the JSON data. One alternative is to use `Object.create(Class.prototype)` if you need to avoid calling the constructor.